# Resize QDockWidget without undocking and docking

Tags: c++, qt

I found a weird behaviour of QDockWidget when I tried to insert it into own application. The problem is that after dragging border of widget, it size goes back, so I can't change its size. So then I opened [official qt example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-mainwindow-example.html). But the same problem exist in this example. You can see it below. (After undocking and docking again problem disappears)

[image: qt examples strange behaviour]

Another KDE applications in my system doesn't have such bug, so I think there is some function in Qt which fixes this problem. Please help me to fix this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is to call [QMainWindow::resizeDocks](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#resizeDocks). After that the bug will disappear.